# How to handle very long requests in Rails with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I am using [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for a Rails application (I call it *Main*) to send requests to a Rails API (I call it *API*).

One of the request can be very long, it can last 10 seconds up to 6 minutes. Today I am using `timeout: 600` option which helps to go around the time-out error.

But I would prefer to have a low time-out (such a 20 seconds), and a keep-alive sent every 10 seconds by *API* while the job is performed.

**Question:** how to send keep-alive from *API*?

The design I have in mind is to fork two processes on *API*. One would perform the heavy task, and the other would send keep-alive chunks of response to the client (which is *Main*). Those 2 process would communicate with a semaphore. I can write the threading code easily.

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to send keep-alive. When I `render` from my *API* controller, the whole response is sent and the connection closed. The solution on the HTTP side would be to use "chunked 'Transfer-Encoding'". I need advises on how to apply this to rails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that one of your Main workers is tied for 10 minutes, it doesn't bother you?

Comment: No it does not bother me to have a worker on MAIN tied for as long as the job takes on API. Even if this goes up to 6 minutes. What I don't want it too have an arbitrary timeout and hope that it will cover the real duration of the job.

Comment: Yeah, I see your pings. Still don't know the answer :)

Comment: Did not ping you, was just fixing my answser :) Sorry for the noise